# Python Tkinter ProgressBar in tkinter without ttk

Tags: python, tkinter, progress-bar, ttk, ttkwidgets

I am currently creating a program with a loading bar (Tkinter ProgressBar) in Tkinter. The problem is - that using `tkinter.ttk` is a pain - I have to change pretty much all of my code using that method, and seeming as I am fairly new to Tkinter, it isn't ideal to do so. **Is there any other way of using the `progressbar` widget without the `tkinter.ttk` module?**

*(If I had to use the `tkinter.ttk` module I would have to spend hours sifting through my code and changing it - which I don't want to do!!)*

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not do `import tkinter.ttk as tk`?

Comment: @Xilpex How and would that allow me to use the ProgressBar still? The main thing I have to change is the background widgets of frame widgets - would these foreground/background variables in my other tkinter widgets that aren't ttk be affected? (could I keep other Tkinter widgets with the standard background="blue" code as they are?)

Comment: You can use `tkinter` and `tkinter.ttk` in the same code, they're not mutually exclusive of each other and using widgets from both is quite common. Almost every GUI app I write begins with `import tkinter as tk` and `from tkinter import ttk`, allowing tkinter widgets to be used as `tk.widget` and ttk widgets as `ttk.widget`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tkinter doesn't have a progress bar except through ttk.

If you find `tkinter.ttk.progressbar` too difficult, just change how you import it.

For example:

```
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar
...
pb = Progressbar(...)
```

or this, which I think is the better solution:

```
from tkinter import ttk
...
pb = ttk.Progressbar(...)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! How do you suggest I change how I import the tkinter.ttk module?

Comment: I recommend `from tkinter import ttk`.